# check/uncheck, Checkboxlist in gridview ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 columns in gridview, branchname and its subbranch. Both details are retrieved from database.
1.branch name-->`checkbox`
2.subbranch --> `checkboxlist`
If I check each branch name contains all subbranch name in its subbranch column,
My query is if I select branch name1 all its corresponding branchnames should be selected .
Please help me for this .

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        Height="315px" Width="476px" OnRowDataBound="rowdatabound" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("did") %>'>
    </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkdivname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("branchname") %>' onclick = "checkAll(this);" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField >
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="subBranchname" DataValueField="Bid" onclick = "Check_Click(this)">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SowmiaConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Bid], [Branchname] FROM [BranchName]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: have you tried so far in your .cs file?

Comment: If you want to do without postback , then prefer following link of javascript and call main branch checkbox object  http://niharstechnicalfunda.blogspot.in/2013/05/select-gridview-row-using-javascript.html

Comment: @user3089654 what is your problem i mean error if any and post your  `checkAll` code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, This may not be 100% true but you can get idea by following.
try **OnCheckedChanged="Branch_Clicked"** [Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.oncheckedchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkdivname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("branchname") %>' onclick = "checkAll(this);" OnCheckedChanged="Branch_Clicked" />
```

In .cs file you can do this:

```
void Branch_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {
        int branchId= chkdivname.Id;  // you have to get branchId here
        querySelectSubBranch="SELECT [Branchname] FROM [BranchName] Where BID='"+ branchId+"'";
         //run query using your connection;
         //save your result in some LIST i.e subBranchName
       foreach(ListItem branchName in subBranchName.Items)
       {
         CheckBoxList1.Items.FindByValue(branchName.BranchName).Selected = true;
       }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your `checkAll(this)` is correct

use this if you need `onClick` event

```
<label><input type='checkbox' id="chkdivname" onclick='checkAll(this);'>checkboxName2</label>
```

else use `OnCheckedChanged` event for server controls .